# How to replace values of several columns based on/ another column in R within each row?

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am working on a data set (30000 x 500 ) where I need to replace some values in columns based on data from another column. The problem is that in each row, the reference values change. Here is an sub-example of the data set:

```
#Create a data frame
df <- data.frame(SNP = c("SNP1","SNP2","SNP3","SNP4","SNP5","SNP6","SNP7","SNP8","SNP9","SNP10"), 
                   A_allele = c("C","G","C","G","C","C","A","T","G","C"),
                   B_allele = c("G","A","T","A","A","G","T","A","C","A"),
                   alleles = c("C/G","G/A","C/T","G/A","C/A","C/G","A/T","T/A","G/C","C/A"),
                   line_1 = sample(c("A","B"),10, replace = TRUE),
                   line_2 = sample(c("A","B"),10, replace = TRUE),
                   line_3 = sample(c("A","B"),10, replace = TRUE),
                   line_4 = sample(c("A","B"),10, replace = TRUE),
                   line_5 = sample(c("A","B"),10, replace = TRUE),
                   line_6 = sample(c("A","B"),10, replace = TRUE),
                   line_7 = sample(c("A","B"),10, replace = TRUE),
                   line_8 = sample(c("A","B"),10, replace = TRUE),
                   line_9 = sample(c("A","B"),10, replace = TRUE),
                   line_10 = sample(c("A","B"),10, replace = TRUE)
                   )

df
head(df)
     SNP A_allele B_allele alleles line_1 line_2 line_3 line_4 line_5 line_6 line_7 line_8 line_9 line_10
1   SNP1        C        G     C/G      B      A      B      A      B      B      B      B      B       A
2   SNP2        G        A     G/A      A      B      A      A      A      B      B      A      B       A
3   SNP3        C        T     C/T      B      B      A      B      B      B      A      A      A       A
4   SNP4        G        A     G/A      A      B      B      A      B      A      B      B      B       A
5   SNP5        C        A     C/A      B      A      B      B      B      A      B      A      B       B
6   SNP6        C        G     C/G      B      A      B      A      B      A      B      B      B       B
7   SNP7        A        T     A/T      B      A      A      B      A      A      B      A      B       A
8   SNP8        T        A     T/A      A      B      A      B      A      A      B      B      A       B
9   SNP9        G        C     G/C      B      A      B      B      B      B      A      B      A       B
10 SNP10        C        A     C/A      B      B      B      B      B      A      A      A      A       A
```

For each row, A_allele and B_allele columns serve as reference values to change A or B values in the 10 lines.  When there is an "A" value => use the value from column A_allele and when there is a "B" value => use the value from column_B.

In the example, this should be as following:

- Row 1: Change lines with A to C / Change lines with B to G
- Row 2: Change lines with A to G / Change lines with B to A
- Row 3: Change lines with A to C / Change lines with B to T
- Row 10: The same idea.

The output should look something like this:

```
SNP A_allele B_allele alleles line_1 line_2 line_3 line_4 line_5 line_6 line_7 line_8 line_9 line_10
1   SNP1    C   G   C/G G   C   G   C   G   G   G   G   G   C
2   SNP2    G   A   G/A G   A   G   G   G   A   A   G   A   G
3   SNP3    C   T   C/T T   T   C   T   T   T   C   C   C   C
4   SNP4    G   A   G/A G   A   A   G   A   G   A   A   A   G
5   SNP5    C   A   C/A A   C   A   A   A   C   A   C   A   A
6   SNP6    C   G   C/G G   C   G   C   G   C   G   G   G   G
7   SNP7    A   T   A/T T   A   A   T   A   A   T   A   T   A
8   SNP8    T   A   T/A T   A   T   A   T   T   A   A   T   A
9   SNP9    G   C   G/C C   G   C   C   C   C   G   C   G   C
10  SNP10   C   A   C/A A   A   A   A   A   C   C   C   C   C
```

As there are ~30000 rows, I would like an efficient code to run if it possible.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% mutate(across(starts_with("line"), ~ifelse(. == "A", str_sub(alleles, 1, 1), str_sub(alleles, 3, 3))))

#output with df generated with set.seed(2021)
     SNP A_allele B_allele alleles line_1 line_2 line_3 line_4 line_5 line_6 line_7 line_8 line_9 line_10
1   SNP1        C        G     C/G      C      C      G      C      C      C      G      G      C       G
2   SNP2        G        A     G/A      A      A      A      A      G      G      G      G      G       G
3   SNP3        C        T     C/T      T      T      C      C      T      T      T      T      T       C
4   SNP4        G        A     G/A      A      G      A      A      A      G      G      A      G       A
5   SNP5        C        A     C/A      C      C      C      A      C      A      A      C      C       A
6   SNP6        C        G     C/G      G      C      C      C      C      C      G      C      G       G
7   SNP7        A        T     A/T      T      A      T      T      T      T      T      A      T       A
8   SNP8        T        A     T/A      A      T      A      T      A      A      A      T      A       T
9   SNP9        G        C     G/C      C      C      C      C      C      G      G      G      C       C
10 SNP10        C        A     C/A      A      C      A      C      A      C      C      C      C       A
```

As stated in comments, if column name do not follow a pattern, **Option-1** you can store these in a vector say vars and use this inside `across`

```
set.seed(2021)
df <- data.frame(SNP = c("SNP1","SNP2","SNP3","SNP4","SNP5","SNP6","SNP7","SNP8","SNP9","SNP10"), 
                 A_allele = c("C","G","C","G","C","C","A","T","G","C"),
                 B_allele = c("G","A","T","A","A","G","T","A","C","A"),
                 alleles = c("C/G","G/A","C/T","G/A","C/A","C/G","A/T","T/A","G/C","C/A"),
                 line_1 = sample(c("A","B"),10, replace = TRUE),
                 line_2 = sample(c("A","B"),10, replace = TRUE),
                 line_3 = sample(c("A","B"),10, replace = TRUE),
                 line_4 = sample(c("A","B"),10, replace = TRUE),
                 line_5 = sample(c("A","B"),10, replace = TRUE),
                 line_6 = sample(c("A","B"),10, replace = TRUE),
                 line_7 = sample(c("A","B"),10, replace = TRUE),
                 cat = sample(c("A","B"),10, replace = TRUE),
                 dog = sample(c("A","B"),10, replace = TRUE),
                 rabbit = sample(c("A","B"),10, replace = TRUE)
)

vars <- c("line_1", "line_2", "line_3", "line_4", "line_5", "line_6", "line_7", "cat", "dog", "rabbit")

df %>% mutate(across(.cols = vars, ~ifelse(. == "A", str_sub(alleles, 1, 1), str_sub(alleles, 3, 3))))

Note: Using an external vector in selections is ambiguous.
i Use `all_of(vars)` instead of `vars` to silence this message.
i See <https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/faq-external-vector.html>.
This message is displayed once per session.
     SNP A_allele B_allele alleles line_1 line_2 line_3 line_4 line_5 line_6 line_7 cat dog rabbit
1   SNP1        C        G     C/G      C      C      G      C      C      C      G   G   C      G
2   SNP2        G        A     G/A      A      A      A      A      G      G      G   G   G      G
3   SNP3        C        T     C/T      T      T      C      C      T      T      T   T   T      C
4   SNP4        G        A     G/A      A      G      A      A      A      G      G   A   G      A
5   SNP5        C        A     C/A      C      C      C      A      C      A      A   C   C      A
6   SNP6        C        G     C/G      G      C      C      C      C      C      G   C   G      G
7   SNP7        A        T     A/T      T      A      T      T      T      T      T   A   T      A
8   SNP8        T        A     T/A      A      T      A      T      A      A      A   T   A      T
9   SNP9        G        C     G/C      C      C      C      C      C      G      G   G   C      C
10 SNP10        C        A     C/A      A      C      A      C      A      C      C   C   C      A
```

**Option-2** you may also column indexes directly

```
df %>% mutate(across(5:14, ~ifelse(. == "A", str_sub(alleles, 1, 1), str_sub(alleles, 3, 3))))

     SNP A_allele B_allele alleles line_1 line_2 line_3 line_4 line_5 line_6 line_7 cat dog rabbit
1   SNP1        C        G     C/G      C      C      G      C      C      C      G   G   C      G
2   SNP2        G        A     G/A      A      A      A      A      G      G      G   G   G      G
3   SNP3        C        T     C/T      T      T      C      C      T      T      T   T   T      C
4   SNP4        G        A     G/A      A      G      A      A      A      G      G   A   G      A
5   SNP5        C        A     C/A      C      C      C      A      C      A      A   C   C      A
6   SNP6        C        G     C/G      G      C      C      C      C      C      G   C   G      G
7   SNP7        A        T     A/T      T      A      T      T      T      T      T   A   T      A
8   SNP8        T        A     T/A      A      T      A      T      A      A      A   T   A      T
9   SNP9        G        C     G/C      C      C      C      C      C      G      G   G   C      C
10 SNP10        C        A     C/A      A      C      A      C      A      C      C   C   C      A
```

Comment: Many thanks!. Any idea how to select columns that are not sharing any common pattern (i.e line). The names of my lines are different (Dog, Cat, Bird, Monkey, etc) and I used only these names as a reference.Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I used vars <- colnames(df[5:14]) and worked as well. You save my day

Answer (score 0):

You can use `across` in `dplyr` along with `ifelse`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(across(starts_with('line'), ~ifelse(. == 'A', A_allele, B_allele)))
```

Or `lapply` in base R :

```
cols <- grep('line', names(df))
df[cols] <- lapply(df[cols], function(x) ifelse(x == 'A', df$A_allele, df$B_allele))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I have two comments: 1. I am getting numbers instead of C/G/A/T. In example, SNP1 has 3 3 3 2 2 3 2 3 3 instead of G G C C. the numbers looks like are the same as the ordered letter 1 = A; 2 = C; 3 = G; 4 = T but not sure. 2. Any idea if lines have not a similar pattern (i.e line) and are rather different such as  Cat, Dog, Monkey, Bird, etc. I used lines to simplify the explanation but the names are originally different with not a common pattern.

Comment: @Javier_HV I think you are on R < 4.0.0. Add `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in the `data.frame` call.

Comment: Yes, you were right including string as factors. Regarding the second point, any idea to select columns that are not sharing any common pattern (i.e line). The names of my lines are different and I used only these names as reference.Thanks

Comment: How do you identify the columns that you want to change? You can use numeric index. `cols <- 5:14` or if there is nothing in common you may need to manually add them in a vector. `cols <- c(1, 3, 4, 5, 8)` etc. Use this `cols` in `lapply` solution and in `across` replace `starts_with('line')` with `cols`.